# How to know if the GeoPush activate successfully?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk

I followed instructions in the official document to set my SDK, below is the response result.
I wonder from this response how to know that the GeoPush activate successfully? Thanks!

```
{
"Analytics Details" = {
ETAnalyticsEnabled = 1;
PIAnalyticsEnabled = 0;
PiIdentifier = "Not Set";
useLegacyPiIdentifier = 0;
};
"Control Channel Details" = {
"Last Control Channel Payload Received" = "No Data";
};
"Inbox Details" = {
"Count of All Inbox Messages in DB" = 0;
"Count of Read Inbox Messages in DB" = 0;
"Count of Unread Inbox Messages in DB" = 0;
"Current Inbox Messages" = None;
};
"Location General Information" = {
"Beacon Monitoring Details" = {
"Count of Proximity Messages in DB" = 0;
"Proximity messages in local DB" = None;
"Ranging for Beacons with UUID" = "(null)";
};
"Geo-fence Monitoring Details" = {
"Count of Geo-fence Messages in DB" = 0;
"Currently Monitoring Regions" = {
};
"Geo-fence Entry messages in DB" = None;
"Geo-fence Exit messages in DB" = None;
"Regions in DB" = None;
};
"Location Details" = {
"Last Known Location" = {
latitude = "0.0";
longitude = "0.0";
};
"Location Entitlement in place" = true;
"User Location Authorization Status" = 0;
"Watching Location" = 0;
};
};
"MarketingCloudSDK General Information" = {
"Application Name" = community;
"Application Version" = "Version 3.2 (Build 55)";
"Device Details" = {
"Daylight Savings Time Active" = 0;
"Device Locale" = "en_TW";
"Device Reported Timezone" = 28800;
DeviceId = "BF6E1467-6583-4C24-9C6A-5AE0BD583BD8";
"Hardware Description" = "iPhone12,1";
"OS Version" = "13.2";
"Platform Name" = iOS;
};
"MarketingCloudSDK Configuration Details" = {
"Current Configuration" = {
accesstoken = SWHbycmm9YXSMgqC2zNWb34Z;
appid = "8b8db4ae-7577-45d2-9e74-ae715e69f4a0";
applicationcontrolsbadging = 1;
delayregistrationuntilcontactkeyisset = 1;
etanalytics = 1;
inbox = 1;
location = 1;
"marketing_cloud_server_url" = "https://mc1l5b29vh-phbm5rr-9wvbrb1hq.device.marketingcloudapis.com/%22;
mid = 100024861;
};
};
"MarketingCloudSDK Version" = "6.2.3.0";
MarketingCloudSDKLocationDelegate = "Not set";
MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate = "";
"Push Information" = {
"Developer has Push Enabled" = Yes;
"Device Token" = a798eec7feee05ccad96c06732c729ecc0f11280a2410b7e3a78ef2eacdade27;
"Quiet Push Enabled" = No;
"User has Push Enabled" = Yes;
};
"Registration Details" = {
"Current Registration" = {
"app_version" = "3.2";
"device_token" = a798eec7feee05ccad96c06732c729ecc0f11280a2410b7e3a78ef2eacdade27;
deviceid = "BF6E1467-6583-4C24-9C6A-5AE0BD583BD8";
dst = 0;
etappid = "8b8db4ae-7577-45d2-9e74-ae715e69f4a0";
hwid = "iPhone12,1";
locale = "en_TW";
"location_enabled" = 0;
platform = iOS;
"platform_version" = "13.2";
"proximity_enabled" = 0;
"push_enabled" = true;
quietPushEnabled = 0;
"sdk_version" = "6.2.3.0";
subscriberKey = H712AD07F04001;
tags = (
ALL,
IOS,
iPhone
);
timezone = 28800;
};
"Date of Last Successful Registration" = None;
"Last Successfully Sent Registration" = None;
"Subscriber Token" = None;
};
};
"Notifications Details" = {
"Last Notification Received" = None;
};
"Privacy Settings" = {
"Privacy Mode" = SFMCPrivacyModeNotBlocked;
};
"Retry Alarms Active" = (
SFMCRegistration
);
}
```

---

Thanks for help. I have checked the response I have posted again, and the location display that location = 1;
Does that mean locationEnabled=true ?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for help. I have checked the response I have posted again, and the location display that location = 1; Does that mean locationEnabled=true ?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear that you've asked the user for their permission to use Location nor have you called the iOS SDK's start watching location method.  Not 100% on this next point, but I suspect you should see a `locationEnabled=true` in the first portion of this SDK State JSON object too.  Net-net-net, it is unlikely that you've followed the documentation at all (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/location/geolocation-overview.html).